# Find all $f(x)$ such that $f(4x) + 2f(x+1) = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+1}$, for all $x \ge 0$.

Tags: functional-equations

A particular solution is: $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{x}$, obs: don't use this as a given, this is just to show that there is at least one solution.

What method should i use to solve this type of equation?

Comment: Set $g(x)=f(x)-\frac12\sqrt{x}$. Then you get the homogeneous equation $g(4x)+2g(x+1)=0$. Now it depends on if $f$ is continuous, at least at $x=\frac43$.

Comment: Using your base case, define $g(x)=f(x)-\frac12\sqrt x$ then you need to solve: $$g(4x)=-2g(x+1)$$

Comment: Where did you get this question, and are there any assumptions on the regularity of $f$?

Comment: Without further assumptions in $f$ there are infinite solutions, which I think will be hard to describe in a simple way.